# Haskell dynamic assignment of type

Tags: haskell, dynamic, types

Is there a way to 'dynamically' assign the (correct) type in Haskell. Psuedo-code of what I mean:

```
parseAs text theType = read text :: theType
```

I already found something called 'Dynamic' but I am not sure if that is what I am looking for.

Comment: what is "theType"? why is it on the left side of the "="?

Comment: @Poscat The OP wants to choose the return type using an argument, so for example `parseAs "3" Int` would return `3 :: Int`.

Comment: What's wrong with writing `parseAs "3" :: Int`?

Comment: In a sense, `read` already takes a type as an argument e.g. `read @Int text` will return an `Int`. Passing `@Int` explicitly requires an extension. That being said, how to exploit this depends on how you want to use it. This might be an XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard trick is to use existentials.

```
data Exists f where Exists :: f a -> Exists f
data Dict c a where Dict :: c a => Dict c a
```

With these two tools, you can write:

```
parseAs :: String -> Exists (Dict Read) -> Exists Identity
parseAs s (Exists d) = Exists (go s d) where
    go :: String -> Dict Read a -> Identity a
    go s Dict = Identity (read s)
```

Then you can construct values of type `Exists (Dict Read)` on the fly to stand in as a representation of `theType`. Of course, you'll want to use a more informative box than `Identity` as your returned type, and that may mean you need a more informative box than `Dict Read` as the input describing your type, but it's hard to say much more about how to do that well without further details about how you plan to use this thing.

And let me add, as an aside: I strongly recommend against following this route. Except in very unusual circumstances, there are alternative solutions that are simpler and get you where you need to go. With so little context, it's difficult to give very good advice about what alternative will be appropriate for you; perhaps a fresh question with more big-picture overview of where you want to go and why you think this is the way to get there would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks!! I will first explore your answer to get a better view on how to do this, before I dive in deeper! Nice example.